# Does Resident Evil 7 mark disposable key items like RE2 remake?

Tags: resident-evil-7, resident-evil-2-2019

Resident Evil 2 remake highlights the key items which have no longer use in the game and allows deleting them from the inventory. Does RE7 have any similar system? I don't know if the various "animal-branded" keys have been used in all locks, and the inventory space is limited even after the backback upgrade (+4 slots)...